# the nested function is not performed NodeJS, Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have created a function that is looking for any reservation document with matching _id, if exists is deleted, and next the Book(findById) function is performed which is looking for any books using function(findOneAndUpdate), if exists is added value to quantity +1.But i don't know why but the function does not want to be done.

```
router.post('/cancel-reservation', (req, res) => {
  var reservation = req.body.reservation;

  Reservation.findByIdAndRemove(reservation._id, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {


      Book.findById(reservation.idBook, (err, book) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (book == null) {

         //////////// //*WORKING *////////////////

          let bookObj = {
            name: reservation.nameBook,
            description: reservation.description,
            publishingHouse: reservation.publishingHouse,
            quantity: 1,
            year: reservation.year,
            sites: reservation.sites
          };

          var book = new Book(bookObj);

          book.save()
            .then(function (book) {
              res.json(book)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              res.json('not saved')
            })


         //////////// //*WORKING *////////////////


        } else if (book) {

          // findOneAndUpdate
         //////////// //*HERE IS PROBLEM *////////////////

          book.quantity = book.quantity+1; 

          console.log(book._id)

          Book.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: book._id },
            { $set: { quantity : book.quantity } }, { upsert: true }),
            ((err, complete) => {
              if(err) console.log('errrrrr');
              else {
                console.log(complete)
                console.log('complete')
                  res.json(complete)

              }
            })
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

this problem may be related to the fact that the findOneAndUpdate function is nested in findById?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: no, only is displayed book._id in console log later is nothing : 

GET /list-books 200 4.092 ms - 574
5a6c5095ce76fa20fc4b1c65

Comment: The problem is rather related to a bad IDE that does not tell you that there are two parentheses wrong (`)(` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have an extra parentheses on the `findOneAndUpdate`

```
Book.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: book._id },
       { $set: { quantity : book.quantity } }, { upsert: true },
       (err, complete) => {
         if(err) console.log('errrrrr');
         else {
           console.log(complete)
           console.log('complete')
             res.json(complete)

         }
       })
```